# Why using worksheet name in formula makes it fail after sorting?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for any documentation or explanation for something that happens in Excel and I think it's a bug, unless somebody can throw some light in this.

Recreate this fail is very easy:

[image]

The above data is in a worksheet named `Hoja1`.

First column are typed values.

Second column is a formula like this: `=Hoja1!A2` and drag down

Third column is a formula like this: `=A2` and drag down.

I know the formula in second column wouldn't be the proper way (no need to reference the worksheet name if you are referencing cells in same worksheet), but it's needed to check this behaviour.

Now, just sort data using first column as criteria (order from min to max). I was expecting formulas would still show the most left cell value, but see what happens:

[image]

I was not expecting that at all. I tought that because I've used relative references in `=Hoja1!A2`, it would be increasing row number. but not at all. Formulas look like this:

[image]

Solution to this is easy, I must use clearly notation excluding worksheet name when referencing cells in same worksheet, but this behaviour is wrong for me.

I've search on Google, Microsoft Forums and also SO and found nothing about this behaviour when referencing cells in **same** worksheet using worksheet name.

As I said, I know the solution, but I was expecting somebody share any info about this issue.

That's all. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Previously (for example) https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-table-with-formulas-wont-sort-properly/56a70898-bee5-4226-8d96-72f05f49eb11

Comment: I couldn't find that, my bad, never tought of searching for "bug sorting". I focused on searching references terms.

So it's looks like it's kind of a bug reading that. @TimWilliams If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug/feature/"by design" - eg see:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-table-with-formulas-wont-sort-properly/56a70898-bee5-4226-8d96-72f05f49eb11